# Parsing json response from Http Request in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I need to parse a json response containing two keys.
The response looks like

```
{
status: 0;
message: 'some error 404'
}
```

In pure nodejs or React you could just simply do: `if (response.status===1)console.log('success')`.

However, I've been having a tough time doing this in angular. Could someone guide me and tell me how could I parse the JSON Response?
I have attached a mock-up of the code.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-employee',
    templateUrl: './create-employee.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-employee.component.css']
})

export class CreateEmployeeComponent {
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { };
    
    onFormSubmit() {
        let options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        };
        
        let body = new URLSearchParams();
        body.set('data', 'stackoverflow');
            

        this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/createEmployee', body.toString(), options)
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Are you not able to access the properties? What is the output of the `console.log` statements?

Comment: The error was property 'status' does not exist on type 'Object'. I was implementing the interface incorrectly. The author with the accepted answer was able to solve it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6), Angular can parse for you objects from string responses if you tell it how to do it. You can use this as an example.

First define an interface inside your component just below your imports:

```
  export interface Response {
    status: number,
    message: string
  }
```

This tells angular how to parse the json response from your server. The final bit is to use this interface in your post request like this:

```
this.http.post<Response>('http://localhost:8080/createEmployee', body.toString(), options)
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.message);
        });
```